# MySQL Opened_tables keeps increasing

Tags: cache, mysql5.6

I am running `mysql-5.6.36`.

Parameter `table_open_cache` was 2000. I had a huge `Opened_tables` versus `Open_tables` ratio (ie. 67988/1950 after 326 days).

So I set `table_open_cache` to 2500. After restarting the service, I monitored the ratio and I still see it going up.
- From 361/354 after 8 min
- To 1321/1113 after 96 min

Why is the ratio increasing even though the server is still far from hitting the `table_open_cache` value.

Regards
Santiago

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Created_tmp_tables';` because `Opened_tables` will increase every time a temporary table is increased.

Also I'd recommend graphing these values (`Opened_tables`, `Open_tables`, `Created_tmp_tables`) over time so you can get a better indication rather than sporadic sampling.